# X & Y update Scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Data1
+++++++++++++++++
|Name    | Grade|
++++++++++++++++
|Tom     |  A   |
|NULL    |  B   |
|Bill    |  NULL|
+++++++++++++++++
```

Lets say, I have a table "Data1" as described above. 
I write a dynamic query that would retrieve NOT NULL values from Data1 for Name and Grade Columns.

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(255)
SET @Query = SELECT * from Data1 WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND Grade IS NOT NULL
```

Upon executing the @query

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

I should get the result:

```
+++++++++++++++++
|Name    | Grade|
++++++++++++++++
|Tom     |  A   |
+++++++++++++++++
```

Is it possible to write @query in such a way that Data1 gets updated with the result of executing @Query, that is: table Data1 to only hold this value

```
Updated Data1 table
+++++++++++++++++
|Name    | Grade|
++++++++++++++++
|Tom     |  A   |
+++++++++++++++++
```

within it going forward and delete the rest, Is it possible?

I know one option is to write into another table and then update Data1 based on values of that table, but I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way of updating table: Data1
without creating more table?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `Data1` gets updated with the result? The result set you have is already in that table, so what are you trying to do here? Also, why does the query need to be dynamic? There's nothing dynamic about it.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, When I execute the Query it gives me result Name: Tom and Grade: A. I want the table Data1 to only hold this value within it going forward and delete the rest, Is it possible? I know the query is not that advanced as I am just getting the concept cleared at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement, here, you are after is:

```
DELETE FROM Data1
WHERE [Name] IS NULL
   OR Grade IS NULL;
```

There's no reason for this query to be dynamic. I have the feeling here, however, that this is probably an xy question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
DELETE d 
FROM Data1 d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Data1 d1
                  WHERE d1.NAME = d.NAME AND d1.GRADE = d.GRADE AND 
                        d1.NAME IS NOT NULL AND d1.GRADE IS NOT NULL
                 )
GO

SELECT *
FROM Data1 d;
```